# Heroku java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionErrorUnsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, heroku

Im trying to deploy a simple Java EE app on heroku cloud using Cedar stack.

Im getting “**java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/app/myApp/main : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class com.app.myApp.main**"

Which means that Im compiling with a higher JDK version than the heroku JVM version. 
I specified **“java.runtime.version=1.7”** in my **“system.properties”** file.

I tried JDK to recompile with these other JDK versions:

•   jdk1.7.0_55

•   jdk1.7.0_51

•   jdk1.7.0_07

For example when I tried "jdk1.7.0_07" , in order to confirm that Im using the correct JDK version jdk1.7.0_07 to compile , I issued "javac -version" , got:

[image]

Than I also check that Eclipse is using the correct JDK version jdk1.7.0_07:

[image]

Than i compile & create WAR using *"mvn clean package"* , **than i deployed using "heroku deploy:war --war myApp.war --app myApp"**

But I still get:

**“java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/app/myApp/main : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class com.app.myApp.main"**

And than I tried JDK 6 version , just in case Heroku JVM was versio 6

Using system.properties file “java.runtime.version=1.6

•   jdk1.6.0_45

•   jdk1.6.0_34

I compiled/packaged & deployed , but I still get:

**“java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/app/myApp/main : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class com.app.myApp.main"**

Finally said this is enough , and tried to run **“heroku run bash”** so I can remote into heroku & try to find the JVM version by; either issuing **“java –version” or  "cd" into “.jdk” path & actually inspect what JVM that is being used, b**ut I kept keep getting “Timeout awaiting process”…** with no bash console.**

**Therefore what is the actual JVM version installed on Heroku instance & how can one find out???**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class files are compiled for Java7.
But it seems that "Heroku" uses a lower version.

It is not sufficient to include the Java runtime of a lower version but you have to ensure that the compiler creates class files for the required version.

Therefore you have to specify the target version on the Java Compiler page to 1.6 as well!

Comment: it seems my Heroku instance had JRE 6 , that accepted no later than JDK 6 compiled code.